# Output the variable name to console

Tags: javascript, variables, console

I am wanting to output the variable and variable name to console by just using the variable. This must be simple but I can't figure out how to do it. So I want the output I'd get from the below code but without hardcoding the variable name.

```
const myVar = 10

console.log('myVar',myVar)

//OUTPUT myVar, 10
```

SO just to make it clear I want the variable name to be programatically created from the variable NOT hardcoded 'myVar' as I want to automate this.

I HAVE TRIED

```
'[myVar]'
//doesn't work
myVar.name
//doesn't work
```

I HAVE BEEN ASKED TO EXPLAIN WHY

I am sick of writing

```
console.log('myVar',myVar')
```

I would like to create a function that takes in a variable to outputs what I want to the console.

I TRIED

```
const myVar = 10

const outVar = (myVar) =>{
console.log({somethingHere}, myVar)
}
//somethingHere is a placeholder for the correct syntax

outvar(myVar)
//expected Outcome  myVar, 10
```

Comment: The issue with writing a generic function to do this is that the parameter name on the function is not tied to the original variable that passes in the value.  So there is no way to grab the name that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to know the variable name. You can make it as an object with the shorthand property names which as close as you can get to what you want. It is great for debugging.

```js
const myVar = 10
const myVar2 = 4

console.log({ myVar })
console.log({ myVar, myVar2 })
```

Comment: Which you have to know the variable name in order to do this in the first place.  Heh, so this still screams "why"?

Comment: @Taplar I have done it so when debugging so I do not have to keep track of what one it is and not have to type a lot. No clue why OP would need it.

Comment: @Taplar - Quite true, but at least you only have to type it once, rather than twice. I've been known to do this, because I'm a lazy (de)bugger. :-)

Comment: Mmm, that's a good point.  I also often do `console.log('x', x)` when debugging.  Makes sense in that case.

Comment: I have added an explanation as to why I want to do it. Its just I write console.log('myVar',myVar) and wanted to write a function to make it quicker and mean I can format it.

Comment: The closest you will get is this. You will get tired of adding the `{` and `}`.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to be impossible. I thought there would be a name property on the variable - O well